# Check for Online Update in WIX

Tags: wix

I work on WIX installer, I want the auto-update system that ClickOnce provide. I upload the new version on server and the end client can check online to see if there is a newer version available.

Can WIX do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write something yourself to check for updates and download the new installer.  Once you have the new installer, WiX can handle upgrading the version installed on the end user machine.  Typically people have a secondary executable embedded within the main program which is responsible for launching the downloaded installer, so that the main program can close during the update process.

In the past, I've handled checking for and downloading updates with [NAppUpdate](https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate), which is easily extensible for however you want it to behave.  I'm sure there are plenty of other open source alternatives to handle this as well.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I write a code that chack if there is a new version of my application, If yes the client download the EXE file for new application. Is there a way that allow the client to install the new version direct during/after download the new one like clickonve?

Answer (score 0):

Wix does not have the capability to do so.

You can read the diffrences between ClickOnce and Wix (Windows installer) from:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx

I think you can wrap MSI in ClickOnce and use both.

Also you have Squirrel (Like clickonce) that is based on PowerShell but may not work on all target machines.

Comment: Thanks Arkady for the link, I read the comparison, But I can't understand how to wrap both techniques (MSI and Clickonce) .. Can you help to understand?

Comment: Are you familiar with clickonce? if not, i suggest to you start with pluralsight course https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/clickonce-deployment-fundamentals , it's great way to start. After that you will find the way to do so.